# Return to original src on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Context: Im trying to replace an image on mouseover, and return to original on mouseout. WHen i use the original link of the image src, it works. But my problem is that i will have multiple sections of this. I know i can make it work by making a script on each original src and input the image link there, but is there a way to make it return to original img src without adding the hard link of the img?

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <div class="name-wrapper">
        <span id="name1" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 1</span>
        <span id="name2" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="img-set">
        <img src="images/2023/some-img.jpg" alt="Some Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="hotspots">
        <a href="#" data-src="images/2023/some-img2.jpg" data-target="name1">test1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src="images/2023/some-img3.jpg" data-target="name2">test2</a>
    </div>
</div>

$(".hotspots a").mouseover( function() {

        var value = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $(".img-set img").attr("src", value);

        var target = $(this).data("target");

        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).removeClass("opacity-0");
          }
    })

    $(".hotspots a").mouseout( function() {

        $( '.img-set img' ).attr("src","images/2023/some-img.jpg");

        var target = $(this).data("target");
        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).addClass("opacity-0");
          }
    });
```

How can i make it so that instead of putting in the actuall src, it would be original src instead.

So i tried with this and the whole thing doesnt work anymore

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var original = document.getElementsByClassName(".img-set img").getAttribute("src");

    $(".hotspots a").mouseover( function() {

        var value = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $(".img-set img").attr("src", value);

        var target = $(this).data("target");

        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).removeClass("opacity-0");
          }
    })

    $(".hotspots a").mouseout( function() {

        $( '.img-set img' ).attr("src", original);

        var target = $(this).data("target");
        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).addClass("opacity-0");
          }
    });
    
})
```

Comment: `var original = document.getElementsByClassName(".img-set img").getAttribute("src");` <-- `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a node list of elements. As such, you can't access a property of a single element from that node list, you have to isolate one element within that list to work on its properties. Also, don't even use `.getElementsByClassName()` in the first place as it is an old API that has performance implications. Instead, you should use `.querySelectorAll()` to get a node list or `.querySelector()` to get a single element.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you just continue with that? `var original = $(".img-set img").attr("src")`

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you, i was looking for something like this actually, because i will have a few more sections with the same class('img.set img') with a different src, So i'm guessing, to do this i will have to use querySelectorAll()? How can i control which ('img.set img') src will it use per section? How should i look into it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just use jQuery instead of using javascript to select the original image src.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var original = $(".img-set img").attr("src");

    $(".hotspots a").mouseover( function() {

        var value = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $(".img-set img").attr("src", value);

        var target = $(this).data("target");

        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).removeClass("opacity-0");
          }
    })

    $(".hotspots a").mouseout( function() {

        $( '.img-set img' ).attr("src", original);

        var target = $(this).data("target");
        var targetName = document.getElementById(target);

        if($(targetName).attr('id') == target) {
            $("#" + target).addClass("opacity-0");
          }
    });
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <div class="name-wrapper">
        <span id="name1" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 1</span>
        <span id="name2" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="img-set">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/300" alt="Some Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="hotspots">
        <a href="#" data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/200/300" data-target="name1">test1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/200/300" data-target="name2">test2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you! This one actually worked. But the issue im getting is when i have 2 sections like this one here [https://jsfiddle.net/96ucLwkt/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/96ucLwkt/4/)
How will i be able to control that when it's on the second-section, it will use the .img-set img src from the second section?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update.
I just check the jsfiddle code and add some code with your code.
I hope it will work for you now.

https://jsfiddle.net/ruepqkty/

Comment: *just use jQuery instead of using javascript* <-- JQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: @SofiqulIslam Thanks a lot!! This one works exactly how i wanted it. Really helps a lot since i can read/understand what the code is doing. So by setting a global var, i can use it to find the original for each function. Thanks again!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you called

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".img-set img")
```

which will not match the element you actually want. (You get **null**)

Instead use

```
document.querySelector(".img-set img")
```

or

```
$(".img-set img")
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit left field but... There is a way to do this using css only using the `:has()` pseudo class. Put both images in your mark up and then toggle the display mode on the :hover selector.

The only caveat is that this isn't supported in firefox at the moment or some older browsers.

Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGJvhpoE8b4) by Kevin Powell on :has() that I hope explains things.

Marked up code below:

```css
#image2 {
  display:none;
}

/*on the body element, if the a tags in the div with class hotspot is hovered then on the element with ID image2 set display to intial */
body:has(.hotspots a:hover) #image2 {
  display:initial;
}

/*similarly for the other one, display none */
body:has(.hotspots a:hover) #image1 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 text-center">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <div class="name-wrapper">
    <span id="name1" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 1</span>
    <span id="name2" class="some-name opacity-0">Name 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="img-set">
    <!-- added both images but we hide the 2nd one intially -->
    <img id='image1' src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200">
    <img id='image2' src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/200">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <a href="#" id='hover1'>test1</a>
    <a href="#" id='hover2'>test2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is `:has()` the key to this? Just the `:hover` pseudo-class is necessary.

Comment: @ScottMarcus only with a different HTML markup ancestry. (I mistakenly upvoted your comment ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Just save the original `src` on first hover and set it to the event `mouseleave`:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.hotspots a', function() {
  const t = $(this);
  const img = t.closest('.hotspots-wrapper').find('.img-set img');
  if ( !img.data('src') ) {
    img.data( 'src', img.attr('src') );
  }
  img.attr( 'src', t.data('src') );
})

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.hotspots a', function() {
  const img = $(this).closest('.hotspots-wrapper').find('.img-set img');
  img.attr( 'src', img.data('src') );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotspots-wrapper">
  <div class="img-set">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/300" alt="Some Image">
  </div>
  <div class="hotspots">
    <a href="#" data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/200/300">test1</a>
    <a href="#" data-src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/200/300">test2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```